# Meteor is not working inside Telescope windows 8

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am new to Meteor and Telescope

I installed Meteor, NodeJs and Meteorite. cloned Telescope. when i run meteor from Telescope folder to start the Telescope Meteor project. i get following error

```
λ meteor
[[[[[ E:\Work\FutureHunt\Git\Telescope ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
rss: updating npm dependencies -- rss...
mailchimp: updating npm dependencies -- mailchimp...
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'crypto-md5'
error: no such package: 'momentjs'
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
error: no such package: 'fast-render'
error: no such package: 'spin'
error: no such package: 'autoform'
error: no such package: 'collection2'
error: no such package: 'jquery-hotkeys'
error: no such package: 'marked'
error: no such package: 'bootstrap3-datepicker'
error: no such package: 'subs-manager'
error: no such package: 'telescope-module-embedly'

While building package `telescope-tags`:
error: no such package: 'simple-schema'
error: no such package: 'iron-router'

While building package `telescope-search`:
error: no such package: 'simple-schema'
error: no such package: 'iron-router'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

However. when i create a new project of meteor using "meteor create newproject" and run it. it works fine. 
I am also using latest Telescope version. and meteor is in my PATH variable. i can't figure out the error.

Comment: Do you have meteorite installed?

Comment: Hello, I followed this guide. 
http://www.telesc.pe/docs/installing-telescope/
according to there, i ran npm install -g meteorite and it showed me 
C:\Users\Singularity Guy\AppData\Roaming\npm\mrt -> C:\Users\Singularity Guy\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\meteorite\bin\mrt.js

> meteorite@0.7.6 postinstall C:\Users\Singularity Guy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\meteorite
> sh ./completions/postinstall.sh

Comment: meteorite@0.7.6 C:\Users\Singularity Guy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteorite
├── rolling_timeout_exec@0.0.1
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── wrench@1.3.9
├── async@0.2.9
├── underscore@1.3.3
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── fstream@1.0.1 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.2, rimraf@2.2.8, mkdirp@0.5.0)
├── ddp@0.4.6 (meteor-ejson@0.6.3, node-srp@0.0.1, faye-websocket@0.7.2)
└── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.2.1, winston@
0.6.2)

Comment: so, no fail message. hence i considered it(meteorite ) as installed.

Comment: Try running `mrt` rather than `meteor`.

Comment: I tried. it was opening some kind of Microsoft malicious removal software.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/65#issuecomment-11428236

you need to manually copy the source for each of those packages into your telescope project directory.

Overall, I suspect it would be easier to do your Meteor development inside a virtual machine.